# Install Kernel to Other Partition

Tags: installation, dual-boot, partitioning, kernel

I have two Linux partitions, each running Ubuntu 12.04. One I was using as a legitimate partition for all my real computing. The other I was using as a honeycomb and a fallback partition. However, while working in the legit partition, I was apt-get installing and removing and I must have accidentally included a * or something. The kernel ended up being removed. When I rebooted, GRUB only listed my honeycomb kernels, so now I can only boot to the honeycomb. I was messing around with Cinnamon and GNOME and trying new things out and I got carried away.

The entire filesystem from the legit partition seems to be intact, and the /boot directory had only a grub folder in it and a memtest file.

How can I install a kernel into the legit partition, FROM the honeycomb?

Answer (score 3):

You could do a chroot into the partition with missing kernel:

- `sudo mkdir /mnt/ubuntu`
- `sudo mount /dev/ubuntuPartitionWithMissingKernel /mnt/ubuntu`
- `sudo mount -t proc proc /mnt/ubuntu/proc`
- `sudo mount -t sysfs sys /mnt/ubuntu/sys`
- `sudo mount -t devtmpfs /dev /mnt/ubuntu/dev`
- `sudo mount -t devpts /dev/pts /mnt/ubuntu/dev/pts`
- `sudo cp -L /etc/resolv.conf /mnt/ubuntu/etc/resolv.conf`
- `sudo chroot /mnt/ubuntu /bin/bash`
- `source /etc/profile`

Then you can install the missing kernel via apt-get. (I'm not sure if you have to update the bootloader configuration file afterwards or if it is done automatically after installing the kernel. If not run `sudo update-grub`).

You don't have to chroot from your honeycomb, you can use a Ubuntu LiveCD for that.

If you aren't able to install the kernel via apt-get you can copy the initrd.img file and the vmlinuz file from a LiveCD in /boot to /boot in your partition without kernel and update the bootloader, this way it'll at least boot.